# MongoDB. How to carry calculated fields through an aggregation pipeline?

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to gather some insights from some OSM data in json form. Here's an example of the documents I'm using in MongoDB/PyMongo:

```
{"amenity": "post_office",
 "name": "Dominion Road Postshop", 
 "created": {"uid": "10829", 
             "changeset": "607706", 
             "version": "5", 
             "user": "myfanwy",   
              "timestamp": "2007-11-24T12:41:04Z"}, 
 "pos": [-36.8801299, 174.7495053], 
 "created_by": "Potlatch 0.5d", 
 "type": "node", 
 "id": "61076379"}
```

So each document has a user and an amenity. I want to find the count of each amenity each user records, divided by the total amount of amenities that each user records.

So to help clarify here are the code snippets I'd use to find each individual count:

Query 1. Finding how many of each amenity each user records:

```
amenity_per_user = coll.aggregate([{"$match":{"amenity":{"$exists":True}}},
                               {"$group":{"_id":{"user":"$created.user", "amenities":"$amenity"}, "count":{"$sum":1}}},
                               {"$sort":{"count":-1}}])
```

Query 2. Find how many amenities each user records:

```
results = coll.aggregate([{"$match":{"amenity":{"$exists":True}}},
                      {"$group":{"_id":"$created.user", "count":{"$sum":1}}},
                      {"$sort":{"count":-1}}])
```

And the answers for both are(limited to 5 results each):

```
Finding how many of each amenity each user records:
{u'_id': {u'amenities': u'parking', u'user': u'Rudy355'}, u'count': 1886}
{u'_id': {u'amenities': u'post_box', u'user': u'Rudy355'}, u'count': 547}
{u'_id': {u'amenities': u'telephone', u'user': u'Rudy355'}, u'count': 485}
{u'_id': {u'amenities': u'parking', u'user': u'myfanwy'}, u'count': 451}
{u'_id': {u'amenities': u'restaurant', u'user': u'Rudy355'}, u'count': 429}
Find how many amenities each user records:
{u'_id': u'Rudy355', u'count': 6321}
{u'_id': u'myfanwy', u'count': 951}
{u'_id': u'Robert Ancell', u'count': 599}
{u'_id': u'lcmortensen', u'count': 366}
{u'_id': u'Marks2000', u'count': 228}
```

Now what I want to do is divide the amount for each users top amenity (ie.Rudy355 made 1886 entries for the parking amenity) by their total amount of recordings(Query 2). - So one end result would be that Rudy355 made 0.3 of his recordings in the 'parking' amenity. - 1886/6321=0.3.

This is what I've got to:

```
coll.aggregate([{"$match":{"amenity":{"$exists":True}}},
                    {"$group":{"_id":"$created.user", "user_count":{"$sum":1}}},
                    {"$group":{"_id":{"user":"$created.user", "amenities":"$amenity"}, "amenity_count":{"$sum":1}, 
                               "ucount":{"$push":"$user_count"}}},
                    {"$unwind":"$ucount"},
                    {"$project":{"$divide":{"$ucount", "$amenity_count"}}},
                    {"$sort":{"count":-1}}])
```

Any help would be awesome!

By the way I really don't like the idea of using $push to save the value for 'user_count'. Does anyone know of a better way of saving calculated fields like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation. `$push` to save the each `amenity` and its `count` to be later used for calculating `record` with `total` user amenity count.

```
 [
    {"$match":{"amenity":{"$exists":True}}},
    {"$group":{"_id":{"user":"$created.user", "amenity":"$amenity"}, "count":{"$sum":1}}},
    {"$group":{"_id":"$_id.user", "total":{"$sum":"$count"}, "amenities":{"$push":{amenity:"$_id.amenity","count":"$count"}}}},
    {"$unwind":"$amenities"},
    {"$project:{"_id":0,"user":"$_id", "amenity":"$amenities.amenity", record":{"$divide":{"$amenities.count", "$total"}}}},
    {"$sort":{"record":-1}}
]
```

You should have output like below.

```
{"user":"Rudy355", "amenity":"parking", "record":0.3}
```